# passing variables from python to mySQL db

Tags: python, mysql

I seem to have a problem understanding how to pass variables from python to mySQL db.
for example, I have this piece of code:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET %s = %s + 1 WHERE name = %s", (variable1,variable2,judge))
```

where im trying to increment a certain value in the db, and im getting
and error in mySQL syntax.
but somehow in another part of my code im basically doing the same thing and it works, for example, this works fine:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT row FROM Table WHERE name IN (%s)", (name))
```

somehow I feel there's some inconsistency with the way I should pass arguments to the mySQL piece of code.

any suggestions on what I should do in this case and generally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values passed in the second argument to `cursor.execute` must be *field values*. The can not be the names of fields or tables themselves.

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET %s = %s + 1 WHERE name = %s", (variable1,variable2,judge))
```

fails because `variable1` (and possibly `variable2`) are a field (column) names.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT row FROM Table WHERE name IN (%s)", (name,))
```

succeeds because `name` is a value.
Note I added a comma after `name` since the second argument must be a sequence.

---

Field and table names have to be part of the SQL string
itself. Thus, to fix the first statement, use string formatting to
insert the field names:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET {} = {} + 1 WHERE name = %s".format(variable1, variable2), (judge,))
```

Beware that using string formatting can make the code vulnerable to SQL
injection if `variable1` or `variable2` is user-supplied. In that case you would need to supply a whitelist of valid field names and only allow the user to select values from that list.

Comment: variable 1 and 2 aren't column names, they are both variable names from the python code...

Comment: For  `UPDATE table SET variable1 = ...`  to be valid SQL, the *value* of `variable1`  must be a table column name. Column names can not be parametrized.